# Will lenses from a Rebel work on higher-model Canon cameras?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount

I am thinking about purchasing a Canon 60D and selling my Rebel XT and wondered if I would need to purchase new lenses? I only have two but as you all know, once you invest it is hard to not take those into consideration when purchasing a new camera.

Answer (score 29):

There are currently two types of Canon lenses: [EF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF_lens_mount) and [EF-S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_lens_mount).

The EF lenses will work on any modern Canon EOS camera (including both the XT and the 60D).

The EF-S lenses will work on *some* digital Canon EOS cameras, including the Rebel series, XXD series (including the 60D) and the 7D. You can see a full list of supported cameras on wikipedia's [EF-S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_lens_mount) page.

EF-S lenses do **not** work on the 5D or 1D series of Canon EOS DSLRs, nor do they work on the D30, D60 or 10D which are three of Canon's earliest DSLRs (not to be confused with the 30D or 60D, which both support EF-S lenses!).

So to answer your question directly, yes, any lens that works on your Rebel XT will work on a Canon EOS 60D, since both support the exact same set of lenses (EF and EF-S only).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...I think I will have to make the jump into a new camera, most likely the 60D! I appreciate your time :)

Comment: Great answer, but for completeness you should add that the EF-s lenses aren't compatible with the D30, D60 and 10D as well.

Comment: To generalize this, EF-S are meant for Crop Sensor Bodies only, EF lens are for both Cropped and Full Frame bodies.

Comment: @2-Stroker, not quite — that was my first thought too, but as MattGrum rightly points out, the first 3 crop SLRs from Canon (D30, D60, 10D) do not support EF-S, which was introduced with the 20D.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case the question comes up, Canon FD lenses are NOT interchangeable with the current Canon line. The FD is the previous generation, so...

Also, for a complete list of cameras that support the EF-s mount, see the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_lens_mount#Compatibility). Of note is that the 10D is not supported, or similarly old cameras.

Comment: Last FD mount camera was introduced in 1990, so the remaining FD lenses are very old stuff.

Comment: There are some pretty old lenses around... It's a good thing to beware of if you're looking to buy a lens from a place like Craigs List or otherwise used place.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other good answers - You did not mention what lenses you currently have. Thus, my guess is that these are the (18-55mm) kit lens and the 75-300mm tele. This is a very popular combination with Rebel owners, including me. Once you consider changing your camera body to the next step in the line (xxD), you may also consider that relative to that camera's price, these lenses are relatively cheap, and together cost about $250 (which most of it can be even returned if you sell as used). So, upgrading from a Rebel may be a good time (maybe your last chance) to consider if lens compatibility really is an issue here.

In the particular case of the EOS 60D this is not really an issue, but if you ever considered a full frame body (EOS 5DmkII) or even converting to other brand, than lens compatibility should not hold you from doing this.