# I want to upgrade my Canon Rebel T2i. Any recommendations?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the major differences between these camera series by Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/788/what-are-the-major-differences-between-these-camera-series-by-canon)

I want to upgrade my Canon Rebel T2i and get a new Canon. Something that is a little more powerful, but that won't break the bank.

I also have purchased a handful of lenses for the T2i. Will I able to use them on my new camera.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at [What are the major differences between these camera series by Canon?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/788/what-are-the-major-differences-between-these-camera-series-by-canon), which should help you decide where you want to go next within the Canon lineup.

Comment: The first question you should ask is why you want to upgrade: what doesn't your camera do for you now ? You may be better to invest in better lenses than to change the body.

Comment: The T2i is a phenomenal camera. An upgrade is pretty much only worth it if you need/want the better handling that comes with a 60D/7D or if you want to go full frame (6D/5DII/5DIII/1DX). Otherwise, your money is better spent on lenses.

Comment: On the lenses: [Are Canon lenses interchangeable?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7491/are-canon-lenses-interchangeable)

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what, exactly, you don't like about your current body. The obvious current upgrades are the T4i, 60D, 7D and then the expensive bodies.

another key question is when do you want to do the upgrades. Many folks expect a 70D and 7Dmark 2 to be announced in the next month or two, and be available this summer. Expect them to be better and more expensive than the 60D and current 7D. So a lot depends on how much you want to spend.

Do you already have a 50mm F1.4? How about the EFS 17-55 F2.8?
Both of these will upgrade your current body.